# Crystal Reports Error 20997

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I've created some reports in CR 7 and VB6 which connect to an SQL
Server2000 database. Then I've created the Setup program by using the
VB Deployment Wizard. The problem is that in some (not all) Windows XP
machines.
I get the error 20997 when I try to preview the reports. Could anyone
please give me a quick help?

I am getting this error at :
cryCompare.action = 1 /* HERE */

I tried registering : cpeaut32.dll also.It is registering successfully.

Thinks.

Comment: Have you tried checking the %temp% environment variable: http://www.vbmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vb-bugs/944/Crystal-Reports-Error-20997

Comment: http://www.vbmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vb-bugs/944/Crystal-Reports-Error-20997

Answer (score 1):

Check your printer page dimensions vs what the report is expecting.  I recently ran into this issue with Crystal Reports 7, Win XP and a Label Printer and setting the proper label size in the print drivers fixed it for me.